# Linq delete duplicate ignore case

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I have example list data like this

> var a = {Apple, Orange, WaterMelon, ApplE, Orange, APple}

I want to delete duplicates from that list and get a new list.
My code :

```
var b = a.GroupBy(x => x).Where(y => y.Count() >= 1).Select(z => z.Key).ToList();
```

but it return

> var b = {Apple, ApplE, APple, Orange, WaterMelon}

how to get rid of that different case? Like filtering system in excel that only get 1 Apple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GroupBy` accepts an implementation if `IEqualityComparer<T>`, StringComparer implements this and offer standard preconfigured options:

```
a.GroupBy(x => x, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase).Select...
```

There are multiple options available including `CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, `InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` and `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

More details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinalignorecase(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok, it works. Thanks. But, i just realize that i can add implementation in GroupBy. is another function too?

Comment: Any function or delegate implementing IEqualityComparer<T>. Though if you pass this along to EntityFramework or another Linq provider, it's best to stick to some of the framework's default implementation.

Answer (score 0):

This will filter it respecting casing:

```
// using System.Linq;

var a = new[]{"Apple", "Orange", "WaterMelon", "ApplE", "Orange", "APple"};
var b = a.Where(x => a.Count(i => i == x) == 1);
```

If you want to get them without respecting casing:

```
using System.Linq;
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new[]{"Apple", "Orange", "WaterMelon", "ApplE", "Orange", "APple"};
        var b = a.Where(x => a.Count(i => i.Equals(x, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase )) == 1);

        System.Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", b));
    }
}
```

Output (case sensitive):

```
Apple,WaterMelon,ApplE,APple
```

Output (insensitive):

```
WaterMelon
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a dictionary that adds the string to lower as key and the string as value.

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string> { "app", "App", "zz", "zZ" };
            Dictionary<string, string> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            string key = string.Empty;
            foreach(string c in mylist)
            {
                key = c.ToLower();
                if(!dict.Keys.Contains(key))
                {
                    dict.Add(key, c);
                }
            }
            var t = dict.Values;
```